# pandas importing error while import pandas in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

When I import pandas library in python 3 it gave me a error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\KESHAV SHARMA\Desktop\VS Code\Compiler\as.py", line 1, in 
>   import pandas as pd
>   File "C:\Users\KESHAV SHARMA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 124, in 
>   from pandas.core.computation.api import eval
>   File "C:\Users\KESHAV SHARMA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\api.py", line 3, in 
>   from pandas.core.computation.eval import eval
>     File "C:\Users\KESHAV SHARMA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\eval.py", line 15, in 
>       from pandas.core.computation.expr import Expr, _parsers
>     File "C:\Users\KESHAV SHARMA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 158, in 
>       _all_nodes = frozenset(
>     File "C:\Users\KESHAV SHARMA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expr.py", line 160, in 
>       lambda x: isinstance(x, type) and issubclass(x, ast.AST),
>   AttributeError: module 'ast' has no attribute 'AST'

```
Please help me to sort out this problem.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using only ast instead of ast.AST

```
 lambda x: isinstance(x, type) and issubclass(x, ast)
```